# In python argparse, is there a use case for nargs=1?

Tags: python, argparse

It seems as though it would always make more sense to use the default action of `store` without specifying `nargs` so the output is always as expected, instead of sometimes being a `list` and sometimes not. I'm just curious if I missed something..

example

```
>>> import argparse                                                                                                                     
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                                                                                  
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')                                                                                                        
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)                                                                                                                                      
>>> parser.add_argument('--bar', nargs=1)                                                                                               
_StoreAction(option_strings=['--bar'], dest='bar', nargs=1, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args('--foo 1 --bar 1'.split())                                                                                        
Namespace(bar=['1'], foo='1')                                                                                                           
>>> parser.parse_args('')                                                                                                               
Namespace(bar=None, foo=None)
```

Comment: Maybe if you want to process generically all your args by turning them all into lists?

Comment: The only time it isn't a list is when it's `None`.  If you want your arguments to be lists, it makes sense to use `nargs=1`.

Comment: hmmm. but if you contrast it with `nargs='*'` which always returns a list `nargs=1` just seems extra work to manage.

Comment: @tr3buchet `nargs='*'` accepts more than one value, so if you are expecting only one value for this parameter, you will have to sanity check yourself, whereas `nargs=1` ensures that you get only one value but still get it stored in a list.

Comment: I totes see the difference between `'*'` and `1`, I just don't understand why you would want `nargs=1` to return a list of one, or None.

Comment: In general, i try to ensure my functions that return plurals always return an iterable because they are then easier to consume as I commented on @hpaulj's response below

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both the default `nargs=None` and `nargs=1` expect one value, but `nargs=1` will put it in a list, e.g.

```
Namespace(foo='test')
Namespace(foo=['test'])
```

`nargs=3` will require 3 values, and put them in a list as well.  `*` and `+` also put the values in a list.

From the docs, under `nargs=N`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

> Note that nargs=1 produces a list of one item. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself.

`nargs=1` is just an instance of `nargs=n`.  It's not a special case.

For you, as an `argparse` user, you probably don't need to use `1`.  In fact to me it's a sign of a novice - unless there's a clear need for the list in the output.  I can imagine, for example, building a parser that programmatically sets `n` to some number, may be 3, maybe 5, maybe 1, and expects the result to always be a list.

Comment: I've read through the docs as well. I understand how it works and the differences between `*` `+` `?` `N`. The caveat that you've highlighted in tan there is the use case I am questioning. I guess I've grown accustomed to the general idea that a function should whenever possible return the same type (`list`, `dict`, `str`, etc). As an example, a function that always returns a `list` is easier to consume than one that returns a populated `list` or `None` because `None` breaks anything expecting an iterable which requires the user to have to check the output.

Comment: "I can imagine, for example, building a parser that programmatically sets n to some number, may be 3, maybe 5, maybe 1, and expects the result to always be a list." There we go! that's what I was looking for. I have yet to need to generate a config parser dynamically and that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Returning `None` is handy, because nothing that the user can type will produce it.  Therefore `if args.foo is None:` is a fool proof way of testing whether the user used `--foo` flag or not.  In any case choose what makes life easiest for you.

Answer (score 1):

The case for nargs=1 for me is that I can use it with the "append" action, then if I want to use the option once, I get a list of one item, if I use it twice, I get a list of two items, etc.